# Disable the Comment module

Tags: 8

Is there a way to disable the core Comment module in Drupal 8? The module is enabled by default, but I prefer not to use Drupal comment system and would like to not have it clutter up the GUI for site builders.

I do understand that disabling a module in Drupal 8 is the same as removing it -- perhaps that's why most core modules can't be disabled.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Drupal 8, you cannot anymore disable modules. You can only uninstall a module, but in the case of the Comment module, you first need to remove any *Comments* field. In fact, on /admin/modules/uninstall you will see the following message:

> The following reason prevents Comment from being uninstalled:
>
> - The *Comments* field type is used in the following field: *node.comment*

By default, the *Comments* field is added to every content type.

> [image: screenshot]

Once you remove that field from every content type, you will be able to uninstall the Comment module from a Drupal 8 site, if there isn't any module that depends from the Comment module. Otherwise, you first need to uninstall first those modules.

As for updating Drupal, updating Drupal doesn't install the core modules you previously uninstalled, not even the ones the profiles you used to install Drupal would install.

Comment: Thank you. I was missing one piece of information: I had to remove the comment field from the Article content type first. Considering that most developers I know stay far away from the Drupal comments functionality, I cannot understand why this was baked in as enabled by default.

Comment: Because it's a core module, does that mean it will be reinstalled (perhaps enabled) when I do the next core update?

Comment: If you uninstall it, and you update Drupal, the Comment module will not be reinstalled.

Answer (score 6):

Through Drush

```
drush ev '\Drupal::service("entity_field.manager")->getFieldStorageDefinitions("node")["comment"]->delete();'
drush cron
drush pmu comment
```

Comment: Magnificent solution. Worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can disable the comment module once every use of the comment fields have been remove.

But you can't uninstall this module in Drupal 8.

For the long answer, see this post : https://www.drupal.org/node/2225029

Even if you removed all the "comment" fields you wouldn't be able to uninstall the comment module.

Comment: Actually, the OP got confused between disable a module, and uninstall it. Drupal 8 allows just to uninstall a module, not disable it. So, it's not true it is not possible to uninstall the Comment module. You need to remove any comment field, and uninstall every module that depends from the Comment module.